# Search for a value in a range, then copy values in first empty row of another sheet

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I tried various functions but can't get it to work.

I need to search for the value `Diesel` and copy next three cells to last line of another sheet.
I need to copy only the values, as these are formula based cells.

My Excel sheet goes something like this.. (the sheet extends horizontally with similar fields)

```
 Fuel   Machine Meter reading   Quantity     Fuel   Machine Meter reading   Quantity
 Diesel CAT 03        22              5      Diesel  CAT 03      54            54 
 Petrol CAT 04        22              45     HY oil  CAT 03      54            48 
 -       -             -     -               -       -               -       -   
 -       -             -     -               -       -               -       -
```

Comment: You can't do this with a worksheet-function (excel formula), you need to use VBA.

Comment: If you don't mind VBA solutions (which you need, as Lance pointed out), is it safe to assume that 'fuel' may be in columns A and E? And do you need to copy over "Diesel" as well?

Comment: The thing is Fuel is in columns A, E, I, M, n so on... and I need to Copy Diesel Aswell..

Comment: what have you tried so far? did you try to record a macro and correct the code?

Comment: I could not record any macro as I am new to this function.

Comment: You CAN do this without VBA by using 3 vlookup functions. See vlookup help for details, and don't forget to set the last parameter (exact_match) to FALSE.

Comment: @iDevelop: Thanks a lot fr the idea... I used 3 Lookup functions with IFERROR value set to 0....   Problem solved!!!!!!!!!!!! :))

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a comment by [IDevlop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78522/idevlop):

> You CAN do this without VBA by using 3 vlookup functions. See vlookup help for details, and don't forget to set the last parameter (exact_match) to FALSE.